# A PHP command to open a php page inside an index.php file

Tags: php

I have an index.php file. Inside the index.php file I am using the following php code to open a "home.php" page from a "pages" folder:

```
<?
switch (isset($do)) {
    case $do=='home':
        include("pages/home.php");
        break;
}?>
```

It works fine. My problem is that I want to open a "about.php" page inside the index.php as well. The "about.php" page is not inside the "pages" folder but rather in a different folder called "about". I am using this php code but it is not working:

```
<?
switch (isset($show)) {
case $show=='about':
    include("about/about.php");
    break;
}?>
```

Can someone please point where I am wrong?
I appreciate your help.

Comment: Always use absolute paths instead of relative paths, this will prevent filesystem paths to arise. You can get the absolute path to the current directory as follow: `dirname(__FILE__)`. Save this in a constant, e.g. `define('IN_DIR', dirname(__FILE__));` and then use this constant.

Comment: Are you trying to create a one page website? If so you may want to consider using AJAX to load content into the containers on you single page.

Comment: No, I am trying to open several pages. But one at a time. Depending which menu button people click.

Comment: Where are `$show` and `$do` variables defined?

Answer (score 1):

Your `switch` syntax is incorrect. Try this:

```
if (isset($_GET['show']))
{
    switch ($_GET['$show'])
    {
        case 'home':
            include 'pages/home.php';
            break;

        case 'about':
            include 'about/about.php';
            break;
    }
}
```

And then use URLs like `website.com/index.php?show=home` or `website.com/index.php?show=about`.

Your first code works but most likely by a mistake. `isset($do)` in `switch` probably returns `false` because `$do` doesn't exist. `$do=='home'` statement returns also `false` so the code in first `case` is executed.

Comment: I tried this code. I am using this IRL http://website.org/?show=about but it does not seem to work. I might be using a wrong URL. For the first option I use http://website/?do=home and it works.

Comment: Remove the extra dollar in the switch line.